# How to provide a logging api in a library

Tags: php, design-patterns, logging, standards

I've written a PHP5.3 library to communicate over SNMP with several of our devices. The next part I wanted to do is allow the company divisions that are going to implement it to attach a Logger to the class to ease debugging, error handling, etc ..

Are there any common practices, standards or rules on how to do this? I would like the solution to be as flexible as possible so one can attach a Logger of choice like Monolog, Zend_Log, Analog, etc ...

I'm thinking in the direction of writing an interface that enforces a common API, observer pattern (which might be overkill and too flexible since we only need logging), ...

**tl;dr**
Are there any rules or patterns and preferably an example on how to implement an API in a library that abstracts logging and delegates it to the logger system of the implementors choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). More specifically Object adapter. Different Logger systems means different interfaces and your application should be able to work with all these systems. Take a look at Pluggable Adapters in "Design Patterns" book by GOF.

Answer (score 1):

That's the Facade pattern and yes everything should be exposed only by an interface. I've implemented something similar, a common logging interface (it's in C# though). Pretty much, you define an ILog interface and then implement 'drivers' which will wrap the real logging service.

The consumer just asks for a logger (LogerFactory::GetLog()) and I think it's ok for the logger to be a singleton, so the factory will return always the same instance.

If you want to use different logging services at once (one to save to file, other to save to db for example) then the Observer and Chain of Responsiblities work quite well here. But it all depends on the features. At the minimum you have only the ILog interface and the specific implementation of it.